# Problem with Axios Get request - might be an Asynchronous problem

Tags: asynchronous, promise, async-await, axios, sequelize.js

I seem to be having asynchronous problems. I'm using react, express, sequelize and mariadb for the entire app. I am using axios in my front end to make the get request. However, the get request always returns an empty value. However, in my backend code I know the request is calling the database findAll().

Front-end (React/Axios)

```
componentDidMount() {
   this.getPets();
}

 getPets = async () => {
    try {
        const resp = await axios.get('/getdogs');
        this.setState({ pets: resp.body });
        console.log(resp.data);
    } catch (err) {
        // Handle Error Here
        console.error(err);
    }
```

server.js

```
app.get('/getdogs', (req, res) => {
  console.log("IN THE FUNCTION");
  const pets = db.getPets();
  console.log("All pets:", JSON.stringify(pets, null, 2));

  res.send(pets);
});
```

database.js

```
async function getPets() {
  const pets = await Pets.findAll();
  console.log("All pets:", JSON.stringify(pets, null, 2));
  return JSON.stringify(pets, null, 2);
}
```

output from server.js

```
nodemon] starting `node server.js`
Listening on port 5000
IN THE FUNCTION
All pets: {}
warning: please use IANA standard timezone format ('Etc/GMT0')
warning: please use IANA standard timezone format ('Etc/GMT0')
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `name`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `Pets` AS `Pets`;
All pets: [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "HULK",
    "createdAt": "2020-09-15T23:09:43.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-09-15T23:09:43.000Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Martha",
    "createdAt": "2020-09-15T23:09:43.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-09-15T23:09:43.000Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Bernie",
    "createdAt": "2020-09-15T23:09:43.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-09-15T23:09:43.000Z"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. An axios response does not have `body` property. Response is in the `data` property, see [Response schema](https://github.com/axios/axios#response-schema)

```
 this.setState({ pets: resp.data });
        console.log(resp.data);
```

2. You haven't awaited a result from DB:

```
db.getPets().then(pets => {
  console.log("All pets:", JSON.stringify(pets, null, 2));

  res.send(pets);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I was just reading about using .then on promises to wait .